# Is it possible for using imap to modify the message of email?

Tags: python, imap, phishing, milter

is it possible to add a pop-up message on the received email?

I have searched IMAP but it can only fetch the email, view the email content.
and I have considered milter, but it only uses for filtering.
My idea is when there is a URL in the context of email, I could show a warning message to tell the users that it is a phishing URL or not.
I would like to make the warning message is available for no matter what email client I am using.

Comment: For instance, there is a URL in the message of the email, and I would like to add some warning besides the URL.

Comment: [IMAP REPLACE extension](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-brandt-imap-replace-03)

Comment: Only by removing it and responding.  It would be way better to rewrite before arrival, but youll break smime.

Comment: does responding mean put in to trash or spam mail box?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already mention milter in your question: a milter would be capable to modify the message bodies and can solve your problem.

The `xxfi_body` callback of libmilter allows you to obtain the message body.
When the `xxfi_eom` callback is called, you can use `smfi_replacebody` to replace the body of the message.
This would allow you to search for URLs in the bodies and append a warning message to them.

Notes:

- You need to add the `SMFIF_CHGBODY` flag to the value of `xxfi_flags` when calling `smfi_register`, otherwise calling `smfi_replacebody` will fail
- Changing the message body may have a significant performance impact
- When configuring your MTA, the order of filters matters: later filters get the new body contents, when a previous filter replaces the body
- As noted in the comments: when you modify the message contents, things like PGP, S-MIME, etc. might break
- You might need to interpret the `Content-Type` of the message (and it's mime parts) so that you can distinguish between `text/plain` and `text/html` messages and append the warning message at the proper position

For more information on how to write a milter application, you can find the current HTML docs in the [sendmail source](ftp://ftp.sendmail.org/pub/sendmail/) under the path `libmilter/docs/index.html`.
There is also an [online version](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/sendmail/sendmail/libmilter/docs/index.html) (may not be the latest one).